# The sum of certain records in one table based on records of 3 fields

Tags: sql

Have had a look and maybe asking the wrong way but can't find a related question to what I want.

I have a table that has 4 fields, an ID that is for another record and then Cost Type, Supplement Type and Amount.

Need to be able to add the amount field of two of the cost Types by one of the Supplement types for one of the ID.

```
PCM_ID  COST_TYPE       SUPPLEMENT_TYPE    AMOUNT
-----------------------------------------------------
2238    AGENT           SS                 85.785
2238    DBCOST          SS                77.9891
2238    DBCOST_TAX      SS                 7.7989
2238    DBSELL          SS                 85.785
2238    DBSELL_TAX      SS                 8.5785
2238    PCCOM_TAX       SS                      0
2238    PCMUP_TAX       SS                      0
2238    RETAIL          SS                 85.785
```

So went to add the DBCOST and DBCOST_TAX for the SS Supplement.

I just don't know how to get into the query to give me the value for each PCM_ID for the above.

My SQL Skills are very limited and basically self taught so here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT SUM (pcs.amount)
  FROM dbo.PCS 
  JOIN dbo.pcm ON pcm.pcm_id = PCS.PCM_ID 
 WHERE pcs.pcm_id = pcm.pcm_id
   and pcs.supplement_type = 'SS'
   AND pcs.cost_type IN ('DBCOST','DBCOST_TAX')
```

It is part of a bigger query but only having trouble with this part.

Hopefully there is enough information here that you can help me.

Adding to this 10 Aug,

Following is a the script as I need, less a few fields that are straight data.

```
Select 
   ID=pcm.pcm_id,
   Name=pcm.name,
   Half_TW_Cost=(SELECT round (SUM(ppc.pax_tw),2) FROM dbo.ppp 
       JOIN dbo.ppc ON ppp.ppp_id = ppc.ppp_id 
       WHERE pcp.pcp_id = ppp.pcp_id AND ppc.cost_type IN ('DBCOST','DBCOST_TAX')),
   Half_TW_Sell=(SELECT round (SUM(ppc.pax_tw),2) FROM dbo.ppp 
       JOIN dbo.ppc ON ppp.ppp_id = ppc.ppp_id 
       WHERE pcp.pcp_id = ppp.pcp_id AND ppc.cost_type IN     
       ('AGENT','DBSELL_TAX','PCMUP_TAX','PCCOM_TAX')),
   SS_Cost=(SELECT round (SUM (pcs.amount),2) FROM dbo.PCS 
       JOIN dbo.pcm ON pcm.pcm_id = PCS.PCM_ID 
       WHERE pcs.pcm_id = pcm.pcm_id AND pcs.supplement_type = 'SS' AND pcs.cost_type 
       IN ('DBCOST','DBCOST_TAX')),
   Range_Seq=pcp.seq,
   Pax_Range=pcp.pxno
FROM  dbo.pcm 
LEFT JOIN dbo.pcp ON pcp.pcm_id = pcm.pcm_id 
where pcm.pcm_id = 2238
group by PCM.PCM_ID, pcm.NAME, pcp.PCP_ID, pcp.SEQ, pcp.PXNO
```

The results i get are as follows:

```
ID     Name                   Half_TW_Cost Half_TW_Sell  SS_Cost      Range_Seq  Pax_Range
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2238   Brett test PCM Output  106.1200     117.5300      546913.1800  1          10
2238   Brett test PCM Output  99.7200      110.2400      546913.1800  2          15
2238   Brett test PCM Output  96.2400      106.2700      546913.1800  3          20
2238   Brett test PCM Output  94.1500      103.8900      546913.1800  4          25
2238   Brett test PCM Output  88.5900      102.3000      546913.1800  5          30
2238   Brett test PCM Output  92.6100      103.2300      546913.1800  6          2
```

The value for SS_Cost is the total for the table and not for the PCM_ID.  The value I am after is 85.79 which is the DBCOST + DBCOST_TAX.  I know it is the Agent value above but this is not including any markup on this record and so this will change so i really need the DBCOST and TAX.  Also i can't calcualte the tax as some services dont have tax so it is not always 10%.
Any help just to get the SS_Cost to be the value for the individual PCM would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean update or just select? Please post the desired output for the sample data. Also what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: My SQL skills are also very limited. Having said that, what you wrote looks good ... what exactly is going wrong? Is the value being returned not correct?

Comment: Remove the most outer ( ). Add `PCM_ID, Cost_type, Supplement_type` to after SELECT and:  `GROUP BY PCM_ID, Cost_type, Supplement_type` at the end.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, the system is one called Tourplan, it is a Tourism booking system.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain my solution.

**grouped_pcm_sums** This could be a view.  SQL 2008 supports CTE's which is what I use here.  I like to break a problem apart instead of solving in a single query.  Here just get the sums for the exact data you are looking for and have the correct ID to reference back to in your report query.

**IF YOU WANT ONLY SUMS FOR 2238** I wasn't sure from your post, but if the idea here is regardless of what PCM_ID you are reporting on, to always report SS sums for 2238... then you can uncomment the commented lines and trade the join with a cross apply to shimmy the value up against the rest of your report.

**grouped_sell_values, grouped_cost_values** These could be views.  If I noticed correctly, you link back to your outter query from these sub query on the pcp table.  Instead, you should be able to group by that pcp_id in these separate operations and then join them later.

**left joins** You may not need left joins and the `left` can be omitted if you only want rows where relationships exist.  Since you've performed your grouping elsewhere, there is no longer any need to group on other fields just to get them into your select clause.  You can add informational fields and subsequent data joins at will.  Just pay attention to the row count to ensure additional joins don't jostle your results unexpectedly.

**Finally** I do rounding last.  Check for typos and test each CTE individually to verify they produce the correct results.  By taking this in smaller chunks, you can troubleshoot easier SQL instead of one very large SQL.

```
with grouped_pcm_sums as (
  select pcm_id -- ss_pcm_id
        ,sum(amount) amount
    from PCS
   where COST_TYPE in ('DBCOST','DBCOST_TAX')
     and SUPPLEMENT_TYPE = 'SS'
     --and pcm_id = 2238
   group by pcm_id
), grouped_sell_values as (
  select pcp.pcp_id,sum(ppc.pax_tw) half_tw_sell
    from ppp 
    join ppc on ppp.ppp_id = ppc.ppp_id
    join pcp on ppp.pcp_id = pcp.pcp_id
   where ppc.cost_type in ('AGENT','DBSELL_TAX','PCMUP_TAX','PCCOM_TAX')
   group by pcp.pcp_id
), grouped_cost_values as (
  select pcp.pcp_id,sum(ppc.pax_tw) half_tw_cost
    from ppp 
    join ppc on ppp.ppp_id = ppc.ppp_id 
    join pcp on ppp.pcp_id = pcp.pcp_id
   where ppc.cost_type in ('DBCOST','DBCOST_TAX')
   group by pcp.pcp_id
)
select pcm.pcm_id
      --,ss.ss_pcm_id
      ,pcm.name
      ,round(cost.half_tw_cost,2) half_tw_cost
      ,round(sell.half_tw_sell,2) half_tw_sell
      ,round(ss.amount,2) ss_cost
      ,pcp.seq
      ,pcp.pxno
  from pcm pcm
  -- for only SS 2238 sums, swap left join with the following cross apply
  -- cross apply grouped_pcm_sums ss
  left join grouped_pcm_sums ss on pcm.pcm_id = ss.pcm_id
  left join pcp on pcm.pcm_id = pcp.pcm_id
  left join grouped_sell_values sell on pcp.pcp_id = sell.pcp_id
  left join grouped_cost_values cost on pcp.pcp_id = cost.pcp_id
```

Comment: cocogorilla - wish I could buy you a drink, thank you soooooo much this is giving me the result i need, and you are right it is not just 1 PCM_ID that i need.  It is Sat here so will have a good look at what you have done, with a clear head on Mon but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
(SELECT
    PCS.PCM_ID, SUM (pcs.amount)
FROM
    dbo.PCS 
    JOIN
    dbo.pcm ON pcm.pcm_id = PCS.PCM_ID 
WHERE
    pcs.pcm_id = pcm.pcm_id
    AND
    pcs.supplement_type = 'SS'
    AND
    pcs.cost_type IN ('DBCOST','DBCOST_TAX')
GROUP BY
    PCS.PCM_ID)
```

I hope this helps :)

EDIT (16.Aug)
I created the following code, copied from your statement above and it executes without error (it has no data but that shouldn't matter)

```
DECLARE @pcm TABLE(pcm_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), name NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @pcp TABLE(pcp_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), pcm_id INT, seq NVARCHAR(MAX), pxno NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @ppc TABLE(ppc_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ppp_id INT, cost_type NVARCHAR(MAX), pax_tw FLOAT)
DECLARE @ppp TABLE(ppp_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), pcp_id INT)
DECLARE @pcs TABLE(ppc_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), pcm_id INT, ppp_id INT, cost_type NVARCHAR(MAX), supplement_type NVARCHAR(MAX), amount FLOAT)

SELECT 
    ID=pcm.pcm_id, Name=pcm.name,
    Half_TW_Cost=
    (
        SELECT
            ROUND(SUM(ppc.pax_tw), 2)
        FROM
            @ppp AS ppp
            JOIN
            @ppc AS ppc ON ppp.ppp_id = ppc.ppp_id 
        WHERE
            pcp.pcp_id = ppp.pcp_id 
            AND
            ppc.cost_type IN ('DBCOST', 'DBCOST_TAX')
    ),
    Half_TW_Sell=
    (
        SELECT 
            ROUND(SUM(ppc.pax_tw), 2)
        FROM 
            @ppp AS ppp
            JOIN 
            @ppc AS ppc ON ppp.ppp_id = ppc.ppp_id 
        WHERE
            pcp.pcp_id = ppp.pcp_id 
            AND 
            ppc.cost_type IN ('AGENT', 'DBSELL_TAX', 'PCMUP_TAX', 'PCCOM_TAX')
    ),
    SS_Cost=
    (
        SELECT 
            ROUND(SUM(pcs.amount), 2) 
        FROM 
            @pcs AS pcs
            JOIN
            @pcm AS pcm ON pcm.pcm_id = pcs.pcm_id 
        WHERE
            pcs.pcm_id = pcm.pcm_id 
            AND 
            pcs.supplement_type = 'SS' 
            AND 
            pcs.cost_type IN ('DBCOST','DBCOST_TAX')
    ),
    Range_Seq=pcp.seq, Pax_Range=pcp.pxno
FROM 
    @pcm AS pcm
    LEFT JOIN 
    @pcp AS pcp ON pcp.pcm_id = pcm.pcm_id 
WHERE 
    pcm.pcm_id = 2238
GROUP BY 
    pcm.pcm_id, pcm.name, pcp.pcp_id, pcp.seq, pcp.pxno
```

If that does not run for you, which database (including version) are you using?

Comment: Hi Munyul,This gives me the result I am looking for when run as is but when i add it to the whole query i get the following error: Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
What I am trying to achieve is a query that can be run in an excel sheet as a custom report, the software company as a connector that gets the info from the DB and then it can be organised in a pivot table.  The full query is what I am trying to put together and I think it is beyond my SQL skill set.  thanks for your help.

Comment: As I've already said, I'm no SQL expert either, and without seeing the entire statement there isn't anything more I can add...

Comment: I added to the original more details above if anyone can help.

Comment: munyul, thanks, i also get no data but will have a look at it to see why.  Thank you for you time and help

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the tax amount at all ? It looks like it's 10% of the cost so why don't you just calculate it when you pull your report ?